# Obtaining DocumentReference of Firestore document without fetching document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to obtain the `DocumentReference` of a doc in `Firestore` in order to update its content as part of a `batch` update. I don't need any of the data of that document, only its reference, and therefore would like an other way to obtain the ref than running the usual `firestore.collection().doc().get()`, which would account for one `read` operation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firestore.collection().doc()` returns a DocumentReference without reading anything.  You have no obligation to call `get()` on it.  You can do whatever you want with that reference - it is just an immutable pointer to a document that may or may not actually exist.